# $\int\frac{9x+9}{(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)}dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Integral of $\frac {9x+9}{(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)}$

I  am dumb founded by this question.

I know that the integral of $\frac {1}{x^2+4x+13}$ is equal to $\frac 13 \arctan(x+\frac {2}{3})+C$
If you set $dv= \frac {1}{x^2+4x+13}, v=\frac 13  \arctan(x+2/3)+C$
and  $u=\frac {x+1}{x-1}, du= -\frac 2{(x-1)^2}$ integration by parts won't work.

I tried multiplying $(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)$ To get the bottom part which is $(x^3+3x^2+9x-13)$. Incidentally the derivative of $\ln(x^3+3x^2+9x-13)$ is $\frac {(x+2)(3x+3)}{x^3+3x^2+9x-13}.$ You can arrange $\int \frac {9x+9}{(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)}\ dx$ to $3\int \frac {(x+2)(3x+3)}{(x+2)(x^3+3x^2+9x-13)}\ dx$. But integration by parts won't work if you do that either.

Comment: Do partial fractions first https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions(9(x%2B1)%2F((x-1)(x%5E2%2B4x%2B13))) ... and please format your question ... it is unreadable at the moment.

Comment: You can also perform partial fractions in the complex field, if you know this topic: $$
{{9x + 9} \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x^{\,2}  + 4x + 13} \right)}} = {1 \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)}} - {{1/2 + i} \over {x + 2 - 3i}} - {{1/2 - i} \over {x + 2 + 3i}}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x^2+4x+13$ is irreducible, the *partial fraction decomposition theorem* says you  can write
$$ \frac{9x+9}{(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4x+13}.$$
To determine the coefficients, multiply both sides by $(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)$:
$$9(x+1)=A(x^2+4x+13)+(Bx+C)(x-1),$$
 and set successively in this equality:

- $x=1$, which yields $18=18 A+(B+C)\cdot 0$, whence $A=1$;
- $x=-2+3i$ (one of the complex roots of $x^2+4x+13$):
  \begin{align}9(-1+3i)&=A\cdot 0+\bigl(B(-2+3i)+C\bigr)(-3+3i)\\
  \iff9(-1+3i)&=B-C+i(-3B+C)\\
  \iff&\phantom{=}\begin{cases}\phantom{-3}B+C=39\\
  C-5B=9
  \end{cases}\iff B=-1,\enspace C=4.
  \end{align}
  So you finally have to calculate
  $$\int\!\frac{\mathrm d x}{x+1}-\int\!\frac{x\,\mathrm d x}{x^2+4x+13}+4\int\!\frac{\mathrm d x}{x^2+4x+13}.$$
  Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions.

$\frac {9x+9}{(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)} = \frac {A}{x-1} + \frac {Bx+C}{(x^2+4x+13)}\\
9x+9 = A(x^2 + 4x + 13) + (Bx+C)(x-1)\\
9x+9 = (A+B) x^2 + (4A-B+C)x + (13A - C)$

Solve this system of linear equations

$A+B = 0\\4A-B+C = 9\\13A-C = 9$

And apply to the partial fractions.

$\frac {9x+9}{(x-1)(x^2+4x+13)} = \frac {1}{x-1} + \frac {-x + 4}{(x^2+4x+13)}$

Now you want to do a $u$ substitution to take care of the right hand term.

$\frac {1}{x-1} - \frac {x + 2}{(x^2+4x+13)} +  \frac {6}{(x^2+4x+13)}$